# File upload suggestion in asp.net core webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am storing file in my local storage and while uploading i rename my filename and attach `guid` to filename and then save it to my drive.

So if filename is `abc.pdf` then i would save it like this : `guid.pdf`

Its an ajax call so once file is uploaded i also want to show content/delete of uploaded file.

So url will be like this : `/api/document/guid`

But then when i try to delete the file how would i know which file to delete as i am not returning uploaded file extension

May i can do wildcard search but i am not sure whether it would be proper way or not?

Can anybody recommend me the standard or proper way to do this?

**Code :**

```
public string Upload(string path, IFormFile formFile)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string wholePath = path + "\\" + fileName + Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName);

    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        formFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
    return fileName;
}
```